# Are there alternatives to WebMethod in order to bypass postbacks but access Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms, webmethod

So i'm trying to improve performance in our ASP.Net Webforms application.

As usual Postbacks do their best to slow down performance. I've come to learn about WebMethod calls which i managed to get working too. However for my particular scenario i need to access the Session, which is obviously not possible in a static method.

So now my idea was writing a HttpModule to solve this. However this seems like quite an effort, so i was wondering if any of you know about an out of the box solution for this task?

Mind you, this is just a question about wether something already exists. Writing the module would be pretty straight forward. I'd just like to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: When u use WebMethod attribute on a method, you can specify "EnableSession" property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx#vbtskusingwebmethodattributeenablesession

Comment: I do that all the time - to show, for example, the progress of file uploads. File upload happens in an iframe and updates a Session variable as it progresses. PageMethods is used to query the Session variable from the page containing the iframe - so a progress bar can be shown.

Comment: is the access to Session your problem? if yes why don't you use `HttpContext.Current.Session["..."]` it's available in static methods

Comment: @faby is there no difference between HttpContext.Current.Session["a"] = "b" and Session["a"] = "b" on a page?

Comment: no @AndreasMüller i post an answer

Comment: Why even downvote? I was asking for alternatives because i obviously didn't know about this... Especially when i found 3 SO questions, and this is no duplicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your problem is access to Session object from static member you can use `HttpContext.Current.Session["..."]`

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string Test()
{
    string s = HttpContext.Current.Session["Test"].ToString();
    return s;
}
```

refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.httpcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx) for documentation about `HttpContext.Current Property`;
inside that property you have also `Request`,`Response` and so on.

As suggested by @Martin Smellworse

> Wherever you set the session, you need `EnableSessionState="ReadOnly"`
>   and `Async="true"` in the page declaration

Comment: i'll try it out and mark as answer then delete question since i am beeing downvoted for some reason

Comment: As a matter of interest, can you tell who downvotes? I don't understand why some people are so 'holier than thou'. This seems a perfectly reasonable question to me. Wherever you set the session, you need EnableSessionState="ReadOnly" and Async="true" in the page declaration.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse Thanks for the additional info. And yeah... i don't understand either. it's not like there was dozens of questions about this already.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse you're right! thanks for the suggestion. I'll put it in my answer

Comment: Glad you got it working. First time I did it I wasted about 2 days trying to get it to work!

Comment: In my case I cannot make it work with EnableSessionState="ReadOnly". If I take it out it works. When I leave EnableSessionState="ReadOnly" there, I can access the session but it contains only the data added before the page started and anything that I added during the page load is not available inside the webmethod. When I remove EnableSessionState="ReadOnly", everything that I added during the page load is available in the webmethod.