# How do I convert an ASP.NET web method in .aspx page to a restful API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, rest, webmethod

Dears
it is the first time to post here and I hope to get the benefit from your experiences in application development.

as mentioned in the subject, I wrote C# web-method behind.ASPX page and I used to call it via ajax front end code and it working normally.

what I need is to convert this web method to a restful API that I can test via the postman.
here is my web method:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string check (string order)
    {

  
        if (some conditions)
        {
            return "false";
        }

        else 
        {
           return "true";

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should be able to call that method from the postman something like `url: '/MyPage.aspx/check'`. Did you try it?

Comment: when I try to call the method using the way you mentioned I get an error Exceeded maxRedirects because I am using session["user"] in page load if empty redirect to login page and I can not bypass page load function when calling the web method from external tool or project like postman.

Comment: Okay, so your question turned into a completely different one. This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083731/are-there-alternatives-to-webmethod-in-order-to-bypass-postbacks-but-access-sess

Comment: Also, it does not sound good to call API method which is supposed to be used for logged-in users. I recommend you to consider moving that web-method to different place.

Comment: My issue is not how to access the session in web method , the issue is that I can not call web method via URL or postman and I thought that it related to page load because it uses a session

Answer (score 0):

All web methods support both soap/xml, and REST formats out of the box.

So, you don't have to do anything.

You can put/pass the URL and paramters you have.

So, for example, you have this:

```
public static string check (string order)
```

so, while you can use soap, or even jQuery.POST? You find that the above url is also now valid

eg:

```
www.mywebsite/mywebpage.aspx/check&?order=134
```

So, URL's and rest calls should work just fine - and as a general rule, you don't have to do anything at all.

## Edit:

Ok, for a aspx page and web method, I can't seem to get this to work - (so, I had thought that BOTH a aspx, and a asmx page would work the same. This DOES work for a asmx (web serivce page). However, try adding this to web config:

```
  <system.web>

     --- in above node, as child note this

<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Comment: I appreciate your quick support. the issue is that when I try to call the method using the way you mentioned I get an error Exceeded maxRedirects because I am using session["user"] in page load  if empty redirect to login page  and I can not bypass page load function when calling the web method from external tool or project like postman.

Comment: page load, and even all controls on that web page cannot be used when you call a web method. They are like a ajax call - the web page class instance is NOT used, and you can't use viewstate, nor can that web method use any controls on that page. Nor do any scoped variables for code on that page exist.  Only that ONE routine exists in that context as opposed to a page post-back, not the page class object and values. You can use session, but page load should not fire at all. That's why you have to put "static" for the scope of that web method - it is a stand alone routine when called.

Comment: And I don't see why postman would not work at all - it should

Comment: I got this error in postman _Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop http://localhost/infor/startpack.aspx/endpack.aspx_

Comment: see my edit - my suggesting as noted works fine for a asmx page, but for a aspx page, it can work, but you still have to add correct headers

Comment: I tried your suggestion and unfortunately it did not work .

Comment: As noted, for my asmx pages, direct entry even into a browser of URL + web method name works fine. So before trying to use postman, from browser try a URL. My mistake that this works for aspx pages, but for asmx pages the above working fine. As noted, before trying postman try entry of URL into browser. If that works then Post man will also